# Navigate programmatically to viewcontroller inside navigationcontroller & tabbarcontroller on another storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I need to go programmatically to a viewcontroller from another Storyboard. From here easy. But the problem is: that viewController is embedded in a navigation controller, and this one into a tabBarController (see image)

[image]

I've tried:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Inside", bundle: nil)

    let viewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "controller_id")
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewcontroller)

    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What I get with this is: I go to the correct controller, with navigation controller working, but no tabbarcontroller

Another try:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Inside", bundle: nil)

    let tabbar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab_id")
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabbar)

    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In this case, tabbar is working, but no navigationcontroller.

And... try number 3:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Inside", bundle: nil)
    let tabbar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab_id")
    let viewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "race_id")

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabbar)

    navigationController.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: false)

    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In this case, the behaviour is so strange... I appear in the correct controller, but with a back button. If I click I go to the same correct controller... with the tabbarcontroller... and then navigationcontroller disappear... nice :S

Any way to go programmatically to the correct controller and get working the tabbar & navigation?

Comment: have you tried checking "Is Initial View Controller" in the storyboard attributes for the tab bar controller, then simply doing `UIStoryboard(..).instantiateInitialViewController()`?

Comment: In all examples you created navigation controller programmatically, try get navigation controller from `Inside` storyboard by id

Comment: Where are you to start with? Are you at Tab "A" and you want to load `I need to go here` as the `RootViewController` of a `NavigationController` as Tab "B"?

Comment: @wbarksdale guided me to the right answer. The key is check 'is initial view controller' and present the tabbarcontroller.

Answer (score 3):

Try out below code:

```
var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondStoryboard", bundle: nil)
var tabbar: UITabBarController? = (storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController)
navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbar, animated: true)
```

I have less knowledge in swift. Objective-C code for the above is:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SecondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabbar = (UITabBarController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabbar animated:YES];
```

Comment: It was helpful, just two things: 1) there are some syntax fixes to do, logical if you're good on objective-c and 2) (very important), I marked my tabbar controller as 'IsInitial...' as @wbarksdale commented.

Comment: @XavierGarciaRubio Thanks for the info. If my answer was helpful please accept. Thanks once again.